# What am I doing wrong in my Discord.py Economy Cog?

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, discord.py

I'm using MongoDB to run an Economy system for my Discord Bot hosted on Heroku, it was recently working fine until I tried to move it to a cog of it's own in an effort to clean up my bot however I think I've done something wrong as I'm getting the follow error. I would much appreciate if somebody could point out what I've done wrong in this situation.

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
> exception: NameError: name 'open_account' is not defined

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta
import asyncio
import time
import os
import psycopg2
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from discord.ext import tasks

cluster = MongoClient("securelinkhere")
db = cluster["SGBot"]
collection = db["SGBot"]

class Economy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        await open_account(ctx.author)
        discorduserid = ctx.author.id

        document = collection.find_one({"userid":discorduserid})
        print(document)

        wallet_amt = document["points"]

        em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", colour = discord.Colour.red())
        em.add_field(name = "Wallet", value = wallet_amt)
        await ctx.send(embed = em)

    @commands.command()
    @commands.cooldown(1, 14400, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def work(self, ctx):
        await open_account(ctx.author)

        discorduserid = ctx.author.id

        earnings = random.randrange(1000)

        await ctx.send(f"You went to work and earned {earnings} coins!")
        doc = collection.find_one({"userid":discorduserid})

        total_earnings = doc["points"] + earnings


        results = collection.update_one({"userid":discorduserid}, {"$set":{"points":total_earnings}})

    @work.error
    async def work_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
            timerem = str(timedelta(error.retry_after/86400)).split(".")[0]
            msg1 = 'This command is on cooldown, please try again in '
            msg2 = msg1 + timerem
            await ctx.send(msg2)
        else:
            raise error

    async def open_account(self, user: discord.User):
        discorduserid = user.id

        doc = collection.find_one({"userid": discorduserid})

        if doc != None:
            print(doc)
        else:
            print(doc)
            new_entry = ({"userid":discorduserid, "points":0})
            collection.insert_one(new_entry)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Economy(bot))
```

Comment: `open_account` is method in class `Economy` - so you have to use `self.open_account()` to execute it.

Comment: Not sure about this error, but once you fix it you'll face another issue because your passing the authors name through `open_account()` and not a `discord.User` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you created the function `open_account` in the class `Economy`, and you are calling it from inside said class, you need to do `self.open_account(...)` where `self` by convention, if passed into the function, refers to the class it**self**.

Comment: Appreciate the help! Thanks for explaining it too